# How can I get Latitude and longitude in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

Good Saturday!

I have a MainActivity class and Location class (actually empty). I want to get device latitude and longitude, so in that way call them in the main activity just like:

```
Location location new Location();

location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();
```

I don't know if is that possible, I mean do all the work in the Location class and just get the results in the MainActivity (preferably in a number value)...
Is that possible? Can somebody please help me?

Greetings!

Comment: Checkout the answer seems to be in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Your answer seems to be in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with: 
[The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

Probably you should use the [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

I think that one of the most useful method for you will be the [getLastKnownLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) but that is up to you.

Good luck.

Comment: Rotem, I recommend that you include this as a comment.  This is NOT an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.in Manifest request Internet and location permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

2. make your activity implements LocationListener
3. in on Create method:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

4.// NETWORK_PROVIDER for internet or GPS_PROVIDER for GPS or PASSIVE_PROVIDER for cellular

```
String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

5. // 10 meters radius // 5000 milliseconds to update // this - your-activity

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 10, this);
```

6. in your Implement method:

```
onLocationChanged(Location location){
location.getLatitude()
location.getLongitude()    
}
```